# Change Colors of Cell per Day based on Date in Cell

Tags: google-sheets, formulas, conditional-formatting, google-sheets-dates

I have Column C, RESPA DATE, that has a date that varies for each borrower.

I want to change the color of the cells in Column D, DISCLOSURES SENT, daily within three days of Column C until a date gets entered into the cell.
Once RESPA is triggered I have three days to send out disclosures.

I was wondering how I could format the cell to change to green on day 1, yellow on day 2 and red on my last day 3 until I enter a date then it goes back to a white cell.

Comment: share a copy of your sheet please

Answer (score 1):

- **white:** **`cell is not empty`**
- **green:** **`=IF((TODAY()=$C2+1)+(TODAY()=$C2),1)`**
- **yellow:** **`=IF(TODAY()=$C2+2,1)`**
- **red:** **`=IF(TODAY()=$C2+3,1)`**

[image: 0]